# Stumped by a regex (positive lookahead issue?)

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm stumped by a regex problem.  I've been using them for a project and they have been working perfectly, but then I got to a situation I thought could be solved with a positive lookahead, but my attempt have not resulted as I have expected.

To illustrate I made a line below.  Of it, I want to have two matches returned, the first of which contains "This" and "thisThing" and the other of which contains "That" and "thatThing", where the first value can only be "This" or "That" and the second values can be any (\w*) pattern.

```
adsf(49) asd k:38* K.This(jfkael dk&$% thisThing) and K.That($$$$ djaf aj_dfj^^ ^ thatThing);
```

I thought that this would be something like:

```
K\.(This|That)  (????????????????)    (\w*)(?=\))
```

Meaning, Find "This" or "That" that occurs after "K." and then get the first word preceding ")".  However, I don't really understand how I can specify (look ahead until you find a ")", and then backtrack until you get the word behind it.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but If you're trying to find the content between two discrete tokens(that do not nest inside of each-other), then yes, you can do that with a regex.

Comment: The question is confusing. Can you get more to the point please?

Comment: Please improve your question by reading this short advice http://worksol.be/regex.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I will try to do better next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [non-greedy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
K\.(This|That).*?(\w*)\)
```

or: (if you don't want the close parenthesis to be part of the match)

```
K\.(This|That).*?(\w*)(?=\))
```

This way it will match anything between This|That and the word, but it do so lazily (so as soon as it finds a good match for `\w*` it will use it, and backtrack if there's not a `)` following)

Comment: Great answer, thanks for wading through my less-than-perfect question.  The non-greedy quantifier info. was exactly what I needed to know.  My knowledge of regex is increasing!

Answer (score 2):

How about: `K\.(This|That)\(.*?(\w+)\)`

This non-greedily matches the part between the parentheses, but stops as soon as there are only word characters left before the closing parenthesis.